# VB exception Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to learn VB programming and have been working on a cloud detection project using Arduino with a Visual Basic Forms PC GUI.  I've made quite a lot of progress however I'm getting an occasional error:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOper ationException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.E numerator.MoveNextRare()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.E numerator.MoveNext()
at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualizat ion.Charting.ChartTypes.LineChart.P rocessChartType(Boolean selection, ChartGraphics graph, CommonElements common, ChartArea area, Series seriesToDraw)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualizat ion.Charting.ChartTypes.LineChart.P aint(ChartGraphics graph, CommonElements common, ChartArea area, Series seriesToDraw)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualizat ion.Charting.ChartArea.Paint(ChartG raphics graph)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualizat ion.Charting.ChartPicture.Paint(Gra phics graph, Boolean paintTopLevelElementOnly)
at System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualizat ion.Charting.Chart.OnPaint(PaintEve ntArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintW ithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPain t(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndPro c(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Contro lNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Contro lNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.C allback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I've spent a lot of time on Google trying to understand the problem and find a solution however I'm not experienced enough to implement what need to be done to resolve this.  I believe the issue is with updating data that is used to display three charts on my PC GUI.  I'm guessing the data is being updated in a different thread to the one drawing the chart however I'm unclear how to deal with this issue.

My code is divided into a series of subroutines:

```
ProcessData() ' do the basic calcs
CloudCalcs() ' do the cloud calculations
UpdateHistory() ' update the graphs
```

The subroutine for the graph updates is:

```
Private Sub UpdateHistory()
time = TimeOfDay() ' retrieves current system time (used for plot x axis)
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.Add XY(time, cloud)
Chart2.Series("Series1").Points.Add XY(time, light)
Chart3.Series("Series1").Points.Add XY(time, wind)

If HistoryFull = False Then
j = j + 1
End If

' this starts removing the oldest data points when the required number of points have been added to the history

If j > hpt Then
HistoryFull = True
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.RemoveAt(0)
Chart2.Series("Series1").Points.RemoveAt(0)
Chart3.Series("Series1").Points.RemoveAt(0)
End If

End Sub
```

If anyone could guide me in how to fix this I'd be most appreciative.

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Have you set the `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls Property` = False?  If so, that is not an acceptable way of working with the UI from a secondary thread.

Comment: I'm not sure which line throws the exception - how do I determine that?

Comment: the code includes the check for illegal cross thread calls in the line:   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Windows.Forms.Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

Comment: The documentation around `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is very poor at best as it suggests setting it to false to prevent illegal cross thread control access exceptions, but you should never set this property to False.  You can follow the pattern used in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls?view=netframework-4.8#example-use-the-invoke-method-with-a-delegate) to safely access controls from a secondary thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some help - this worked:

```
Private Sub UpdateHistory()

    time = TimeOfDay() ' retrieves current system time (used for plot x axis)

    AddDataPoint(Chart1, time, cloud)
    AddDataPoint(Chart2, time, light)
    AddDataPoint(Chart3, time, wind)

    If HistoryFull = False Then
        j = j + 1
    End If

    If j > hpt Then
        HistoryFull = True

        RemoveDataPoint(Chart1)
        RemoveDataPoint(Chart2)
        RemoveDataPoint(Chart3)

    End If

End Sub

Friend Delegate Sub RemoveDataPointCallback(ByRef chart As Chart)
Private Sub RemoveDataPoint(ByRef chart As Chart)

    If chart.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim callback As RemoveDataPointCallback = New RemoveDataPointCallback(AddressOf RemoveDataPoint)
        Me.Invoke(callback, New Object() {chart})
    Else
        chart.Series("Series1").Points.RemoveAt(0)
    End If

End Sub


Friend Delegate Sub AddDataPointCallback(ByRef chart As Chart, chartTime As Date, chartData As Double)
Private Sub AddDataPoint(ByRef chart As Chart, chartTime As Date, chartData As Double)

    If chart.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim callback As AddDataPointCallback = New AddDataPointCallback(AddressOf AddDataPoint)
        Me.Invoke(callback, New Object() {chart, chartTime, chartData})
    Else
        chart.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY(chartTime, chartData)
    End If

End Sub
```